# How to open a web page in Mozilla Thunderbird (without using an add-on)

Tags: thunderbird, rss, firefox, feed-reader

I'm using Mozilla Thunderbird (version 15, on Windows) as a RSS client (I know there are others clients; I've used some of them). The problem (for me) is that some publishers don't want to include more details for an article in the description's feed (probably to force a user to open the web page and generate traffic) so very often I have to press the link/title of an article to open it's webpage in my web browser (Firefox). But I don't want to open an external browser, I want to see that page in Thunderbird. Does anyone know how to achieve this without using an add-on (I've tried ThunderBrowse but I had some problems with it)? More explicit: it's possible to click the website link and not to open a new tab in an external web browser, but in Thunderbird?

Note: I know that is possible to select `View->Feed Message Body As->Web Page`. But in this scenario, by default, I can't see the summary of an article (it opens directly the web page; and I want to open the web page only for those articles that I am interest in them).

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, Thunderbird does this by default now when a user selects (e.g. press of Enter or double-click) the feed item in the message list.

Answer (score 1):

One simple solution to have the RSS feed for a full text in the Thunderbird RSS Reader is this *online service*: [Wizard RSS](http://www.wizardrss.com/demo/). Just copy the generated hyperlink and use it as feed hyperlink for your Thunderbird RSS subscriptions. Full text will be then readable directly in Tb.

Comment: Very nice service. I'll use it as a backup solution (if there is no way to open web pages in Thunderbird). However after I've imported the feeds in Thunderbird (after they were generated by Wizard RSS), only the last article is visible (by contrast, in Firefox I can see more articles). Maybe I have to investigate this further. Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: When you add this WizardRss feed hyperlink it's like a new subscription to this feed. The next posts will be readable like with any "normal" rss link...